# Existe alguna manera de notificarme a través de correo electrónico cuando un usuario nuevo se registra en mi app?

Tags: java, android, firebase

He estado buscando alguna manera de notificarme cuando un usuario nuevo se registra en mi app y no he encontrado ningún ejemplo que pueda ayudarme de guía para realizar esta tarea.

La idea es que cuando un usuario nuevo se registre, se realice un envío de correo electrónico automáticamente a mi correo... ¿Es posible esto?

Este es el código donde realizo la creación o registro del usuario a mi app

```
//crear usuario
auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
    progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
      auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
      //Toast.makeText(ActivityRegister.this, user_id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      user_id = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

      DatabaseReference mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Empresas " + PaÃ­s).child(Ciudad).child(TipodeEmpresa);
      DatabaseReference currentUserDB = mDatabase.child(user_id);

      currentUserDB.child("Activo").setValue(activo);

      currentUserDB.child("Usuario").setValue(nombreusuario);
      currentUserDB.child("DirecciÃ³n").setValue(direccion);
      currentUserDB.child("PaÃ­s").setValue(PaÃ­s);
      currentUserDB.child("Ciudad").setValue(Ciudad);
      currentUserDB.child("Tipo de Empresa").setValue(TipodeEmpresa);
      currentUserDB.child("RutoDNI").setValue(rutodni);
      currentUserDB.child("Email").setValue(email);

      startActivity(new Intent(SignupActivityEmpresa.this, MainActivity.class));
      finish();

    } else
    Toast.makeText(SignupActivityEmpresa.this, "Error registrando al usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }
});
```

Espero puedan ayudarme, desde ya, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Si lo deseas enviar usando Firebase necesitas un trigger a traves the Google Cloud Functions. El codigo para enviar emails lo ejecutas cuando tengas un usuario registrado. Link aqui.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/

Tambien hay ejemplos de como usar el Firebase SDK for Cloud functions.

https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/master/quickstarts/email-users